# How to get simple graphql mutation query from generated schema?

Tags: javascript, graphql, supertest, graphql-codegen

I'm using the graphql code generator to get my generated file:

```
npx graphql-codegen --config libs/codegen.yml
```

In this file I do have

```
export const AddDataDocument = gql`
    mutation addData($input: AddDataInput!) {
    addData(input: $input) {
        id
    }
}`;
```

which gives me the gql document.

In my tests (using `supertest`), I'm doing:

```
const query = `
    mutation addData($input: AddDataInput!) {
    addData(input: $input) {
        id
    }
}`
request(app.getHttpServer())
  .post('/graphql')
  .send({
    operationName: null,
    query,
    variables: { input: addDataInput }
  })
```

I do not want to write the mutation manually. I would like to use my generated schema file. But unfortunatly there is a gql defined, like mentioned at the beginning of this post.

Is it possible to generate something to be used in my `send()`?

```
request(app.getHttpServer())
  .post('/graphql')
  .send({
    operationName: null,
    query: AddDataDocument, // <-- but this is not working as it is a gql document
    variables: { input: addDataInput }
  })
```

---

**codegen.yml**

```
overwrite: true
schema: "apps/backend/src/app/**/*.graphql"
generates:
libs/generated/generated.ts:
    documents: "libs/**/*.graphql"
    plugins:
    - "typescript"
    - "typescript-operations"
    - "typescript-react-apollo"
    config:
    withHooks: true
    withComponent: false
    withHOC: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, `AddDataDocument` is a `DocumentNode` object (the return value of the `gql` invocation) and you want to get back the query as a string from it. Is that it?

If so try this:

```js
import { print } from 'graphql'

...

request(app.getHttpServer())
  .post('/graphql')
  .send({
    operationName: null,
    query: print(AddDataDocument),
    variables: { input: addDataInput }
  })
```

I've faced a similar problem a couple of days ago (the "how do I get the parsed document object back into a string" part of the question).

Here's where the idea came from:

https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/144